# Have an Arduino read a string (sent via Python), move a Motor accordingly to input, then receive the next string

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino

I am working on a Rubiks Cube Solver, which uses an Arduino and motors to move each face around. The Python script I use writes a move per line, then is meant to the first line, then the second line, and so on

```
x = 0
    with open(FILEPATH, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        FileEnd = False
        while FileEnd == False:
            try:
                ser.write(lines[x])
                print lines[x]
                x += 1

            except serial.SerialException:
                time.sleep(1)

             except IndexError:
                FileEnd = True
```

The Arduino is supposed to receive this String, stop reading from the Serial, act accordingly as to what is in the String, then accept then next String.

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.flush();
  Serial.println("Power On");

}

void loop()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Read from Serial Port here
  Serial.end();
  // Act accordingly to String here
  Serial.flush();
  //Start all over again
}
```

I am faced with two Problems:

1) The Python script keeps sending each move, uncaring that Serial.end() should have occured

2) When I read the Serial Monitor, I see the same bunch of seemingly random characters that flood the entire moniter upon receiving input from the Python Script

Help Please? :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend sending the commands in G-Code Format.

There are several Arduino firmwares that already accept G-Code and drive multiple motors. 
This way you don't need to re-invent both the Serial Receiver, Multiple Motor Command Queue and Multiple Motor software drivers.

I would recommend [Grbl](http://dank.bengler.no/-/page/show/5471_gettinggrbl) firmware. It will run on an UNO and drive step motors from a variety of shields.

So that your Python can simply send and forget the G code commands, as needed.

Comment: Being a bit of (total) an Arduino noob, could you explain to me in Idiot's English what I should do? Ive read through the docs, but Ive also never compiled any non-interpreted language before :(. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Some code out there predates or is parallel to Arduino but runs on them. Such as Grbl. There are three parts: 1) the compiler, 2) the code and 3) the upload. Getting the code is easy from GitHub. To compile locate the equivalent directories and put them in your path C:\Arduino\arduino-1.5.5\hardware\tools\avr\bin;C:\Arduino\arduino-1.5.5\hardware\tools\avr\utils\bin then from the ./grbl/ directory execute "make" and it will compile it. Then you need use [avrdude tutortial](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/avrdude.html) to upload the ELF file. You can also use WinAVR as an IDE for this.

Comment: If you want to be more ground up and make your own protocol, while being pure Arduino, you can also use the [adafruit-motor-shield](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield) and library. And or the [AccelStepper](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/) (which AF motor shield is based off of). As this supports multiple motors, just with out the G-Code with direct calls to move the motors.

Answer (score 0):

I have a tiny bit of experience with doing stuff like this.
I think pyserial may help in this case http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/
In terms of the serial monitor, I believe there is a way to flush the data before you sent with with pyserial.
There are a lot of stuff out there with arduino and pyserial.